# MMS sender address problem

Tags: android, mms

I am trying to get the address of the sender but I run into a little problem. If the person that sends the message is the first person in any of the conversations to send one, the query of the `content://mms/inbox` returns with zero rows?? but when someone sends any other mms message it will return back with the `_id` fine and i dont understand why the first one wont work right?

```
private String checkMmsMessages(Context context){
    String address = "address";

    Cursor curPdu = context.getContentResolver ().query(Uri.parse("content://mms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    if(curPdu.moveToNext()){ //first MMS message curPdu.moveToNext() is false
    String id = curPdu.getString (curPdu.getColumnIndex ("_id"));

    Log.v("MMS", "ID1: " + id.toString());

    Uri uriAddr = Uri.parse ("content://mms/" + id + "/addr");
    Cursor curAddr = context.getContentResolver().query(uriAddr,null,"type=137",null,null);
    if(curAddr.moveToNext()){
             address = curAddr.getString (curAddr.getColumnIndex ("address"));
             Log.v("MMS", "Address1: " + address.toString());
             if(address.contentEquals("insert-address-token")){
                 Cursor curAddr2 = context.getContentResolver().query(uriAddr,null,"type=151", null,null);
                 if(curAddr2.moveToNext()){
                     address = curAddr2.getString(curAddr2.getColumnIndex("address"));
                 }
             }
        }
    }
    Log.v("MMS", address.toString());
    return address;
}
```

Also something else that does not make sense is when when i have the phone plugged into the computer and step through the that section with the debugger, that problem does not happen and it gets the address every time.... it only happens when the phone is not connected, i just dont understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was checking the database before the message was put into the database so I had to put a delay on the check

Comment: I can confirm that this is not the solution in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are passing a value for `selectionArgs` instead of null to the `query()` method.  I am not actually calling the mCursor's `moveToNext()` method in my code but instead I am implementing this logic in the getView() method of a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + mThreadId);
String[] projection = new String[] { "body", "person", "sub",
            "subject", "retr_st", "type", "date", "ct_cls", "sub_cs",
            "_id", "read", "ct_l", "st", "msg_box", "reply_path_present",
            "m_cls", "read_status", "ct_t", "status", "retr_txt_cs",
            "d_rpt", "error_code", "m_id", "date_sent", "m_type", "v",
            "exp", "pri", "service_center", "address", "rr", "rpt_a",
            "resp_txt", "locked", "resp_st", "m_size" };
String sortOrder = "normalized_date";

Cursor mCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection, null, null, sortOrder);

String messageAddress;
int type;
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String messageId = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://mms").buildUpon();
    builder.appendPath(messageId).appendPath("addr");
    Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(builder.build(), new String[] {
        "*"
    }, null, null, null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        messageAddress = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));

        if (!messageAddress.equals("insert-address-token")) {
            type = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("type"));
            c.moveToLast();
        }
    }
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: `type=137` is used to get only the incoming messages from the database table since the table has 2 different types in it, `151` which is the message you sent and `137` is the message you received

Answer (score 0):

```
try this...


    private String getAddressNumber(String id) {
            String selectionAdd = new String("msg_id=" + id);
            String uriStr = MessageFormat.format("content://mms/{0}/addr", id);
            Uri uriAddress = Uri.parse(uriStr);
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriAddress, null, selectionAdd, null, null);

            String phoneNum = null;
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
                    if (number != null) {
                        boolean isNumberFormat = true;
                        try {
                            Long.parseLong(number.replace("-", ""));
                            phoneNum = number;
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // ex) "insert-address-token"
    //                        if (phoneNum == null) {
    //                            phoneNum = number;
    //                        }
                            isNumberFormat = false;
                        }
                        if (isNumberFormat)
                            break;
                    }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return phoneNum;
        }
```